# Markdown GitHub: Link to image not working

Tags: image, github, hyperlink, markdown

The link to an image is not working properly with new GitHub updates. The code used to display the image is:

```
<a href="https://pixelbuddha.net/icons/capitalist-food-and-drinks-icon-set"><img width='700' src='https://github.com/Anmol-Baranwal/Awesome-Illustrations-4Projects/assets/74038190/3bca40f9-63bd-4727-abc1-d0a577b4d863'  /></a>
```

[Preview of Above markdown code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQZ8q.png)

Now, if you click the image, the link doesn't work. I don't really know why this is happening.
While other images with same structure is properly working that were previously commited.

However, when the image is clicked, the link doesn't work. The reason behind this issue is unclear, as other images with the same structure are still working fine.

I noticed that the new URL after GitHub updates for images is in the format of `https://github.com/<username>/<repo-name>/assets/<unique-id>`, whereas previously it was in the format of `https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/<unique-id>`.

> The image was pasted after clipping the screen, and it's unknown whether the new URL can be changed to the previous one. Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: That exact line, when changing the image source to your [imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQZ8q.png), worked fine for me. The link redirected to the new page. If you're encountering this issue still, please upload more of your markdown, because something else has to be causing the issue.

Comment: How is it working for you? I have checked it in my repo markdown (.md) file, and clicking on it is opening an image in a new tab, but not a link as it is supposed to. Can you please describe the conditions? Have you checked it in the markdown file?

Comment: I'll write it in an answer format, it's easier than explaining via the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the markdown rendered in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ajmeese7/1ec0ccc9454e980e1025c4a5aba5636e), I have simply used the following code:

```html
<a href="https://pixelbuddha.net/icons/capitalist-food-and-drinks-icon-set" target="_blank">
  <img width="700" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQZ8q.png" />
</a>
```

The `target="_blank"` attribute doesn't seem to work in the GitHub rendition of the HTML, but clicking on the image opens the link as you requested, and clicking it with the mouse wheel opens it in a new tab.

Comment: Please visit the following link: https://github.com/Anmol-Baranwal/Awesome-Illustrations-4Projects and search for "126 Significa Icons." Once you find the image, click on it to see for yourself that the link to the image is clearly not working. Interestingly, the Markdown in the gist you provided is functioning correctly. I'm curious as to why the Markdown works in the gist but not in this repository.